# woocommerce rest authentication can't return json result in callback

Tags: authentication, woocommerce-rest-api

I am using Woocommerce rest API to auto-generate an API key and get result back in json. I followed the woocommerce documentation and I successfully was able to log into woocommerce and generate key, but the problem is, the json that should be posted in callback URL, is null, I can't retrieve it, all I get is null. I have been struggling with this error for a week now, any ideas? here is my code:

```html
<?php
$shop = $_GET['shop'];
$store_url = 'https://'.$shop;
$endpoint = '/wc-auth/v1/authorize';
$params = [
    'app_name' => 'appname',
    'scope' => 'read_write',
    'user_id' => 123,
    'return_url' => 'https://appname.app/dashboard/success.php',
    'callback_url' => 'https://appname.app/dashboard/success.php'
];
$query_string = http_build_query( $params );
header("Location: " .$store_url . $endpoint . '?' . $query_string);

?>
```

and this is my callback page:

```html
<?php

ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);


$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback_url dont excute in the browser. You need save the token in a file like tokens.json. The print_r or echo not working.